# Timber/Twig: category archive page not sorting

Tags: wordpress, timber

I have a CPT ('place') category archive template where I would like to display all associated posts in alpha order. The following mostly works – I am getting the category description and photos (ACF data) and the list of posts associated to the particular category, but sorting is not working.

PHP:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();

$term = new TimberTerm();
$context['current_cat'] = $term;

$templates = array( 'category.twig', 'archive.twig', 'index.twig' );
Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

Twig:

```
<section class="places ">
    <div class="places-list">
            <h3>Places in: {{current_cat.name}}</h3>
            <div class="places-container">
                <ul>
                {% for post in current_cat.posts(-1, '')|sort %}
                    <li id="wpgmza_marker_{{post.get_field('map_marker_id')}}" mid="{{post.get_field('map_marker_id')}}" mapid="1" class="wpgmaps_blist_row">
                        <div>{{post.title}}</div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (replace first five lines of your code above):

```
$args = new WP_Query( array(
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'orderby' => 'title',
 'order' => 'ASC',
) );
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Unfortunately, the new WP_Query does not seem to effect the post list. The original code I posted didn’t either. i.e. changing posts_per_page to something like 3 had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [Twig's sort filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/sort.html) and your case, I would suspect two things: 1. Since the order is undefined, it's defaulting to ASC, and maybe your query results are already that way. 2. You aren't explicitly stating what to sort by, and I can imagine a post query is not a simple list.

**Alternatively: Sort in the query**

Although Twig's sort filter is handy and may work in some cases, it may be best to define sorting in the initial PHP query, along with other query properties. This gives you full control, and the power to leverage variables passed between pages via GET or POST.

Below works for me:

**archive.php**

```
$templates = array( 'pages/archive.twig', 'pages/index.twig' );

if ( ! isset( $paged ) || ! $paged ) {
    $paged = 1;
}

$context = Timber::context();

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'post_type' => get_post_type(),

    // Ordering option 1: based on regular field
    // 'orderby' => 'desc',
    // 'order'   => title,

    // Ordering option 2: based on ACF field
    'meta_key' => 'my_custom_field',
    'orderby'  => array('meta_value' => 'DESC'),
);

$context['title'] = 'Archive';

if ( is_tag() ) {
    $context['title'] = single_tag_title( '', false );
} elseif ( is_category() ) {
    $context['title'] = single_cat_title( '', false );
    array_unshift( $templates, 'pages/archive-' . get_query_var( 'cat' ) . '.twig' );
} elseif ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
    $context['title'] = post_type_archive_title('', false );
    array_unshift( $templates, 'pages/archive-' . get_post_type() . '.twig' );
}

$context['posts'] = new \Timber\PostQuery($args);

Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

**archive-book.twig (for example)**

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.twig' %}

{% block content %}

    {% include 'partials/page-controls.twig' %}

    <div>    
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div>
                {% include 'partials/post-tease-card.twig' %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}    
    </div>

    {% include 'partials/pagination.twig' %}

{% endblock %}
```